# Upvote problem in bounty question

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, up-votes

is there any reputation increasing in upvoted answer in bounty question??
I get two upvote on an answer in bounty question but did not get any reputation.

here is my answer: [Pixelated edge around a CSS Circle with overflow: hidden;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882283/pixelated-edge-around-a-css-circle-with-overflow-hidden/19947185#19947185)

[image]

what is the problem?

Comment: Your answer is community wiki because it is in answer to a community wiki question, community wiki answers don't get reputation

Comment: how you get that my answer is community wiki?

Comment: Look at the bit with your user name in it, it's different from a normal user box and says "community wiki"

Comment: I didn't know anything about CW :), thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is marked *Community Wiki*. You don't get rep from such posts.

The original questions was edited 23 times. A post gets converted to CW after 12 edits of the same editor. All answers after that are automatically CW.

You could flag your post for moderator attention and request the removal of the flag.

Comment: That was my understanding also, however 1 answer on that question has excaped the community wikification; http://stackoverflow.com/a/19883668/2187042

Comment: when I can flag my answer? what is the Conditions ?

Comment: That answer was probably there before the CW flag got added yesterday.

Comment: @Mohsen: You can if you like. Shouldn't be a problem removing the CW flag.

Comment: @Mohsen worth to mention that if your answer will be chosen to get the bounty, the rep will be yours. CW post can't earn its author reputation from upvotes (nor decrease it from downvotes) but bounty is not part of that.

Comment: I think it would be fair to flag the question for removing senseless CW, not the answer. Checking [edits made to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19882283/revisions) reveals substantial changes, making it quite clear that CW is not even remotely fair